# jquery Accordion and flashing / jerking text

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am using jQuery Accordion [here](http://projectpath.ideapeoplesite.com/rutland/printing-whiteplastisolinks.html) and find some strange behavior when opening a section. The text jerks and looks dreadful for a second or so and then appears normally. This only happens when moving down and opening the next section. When I go the other way, the transition is smooth. Is there a setting that would remove this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, It looks fine to me in google chrome.  I for the the jumpy in the Firefox.

Comment: Also, there jQueryUI 1.7.2 out and you are using 1.7.1. Maybe there's a fix in there.

Comment: Assuming 1.7.2 didn't fix it... your site runs fine in Safari too. At first I thought it might be a loading problem but it behaves the same with images disabled. I suspect Firefox is disliking something about your styles but the flashing is too fast. Look at http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/3533 for a method to slow down the animation so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things to solve the problem:

1. I updated to 1.7.2 as suggested above.
2. I resolved some issues that caused the page to not validate.

This appears to have resolved the issue related to the upward motion.